# Sync the public variables in a class

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I am new to classes so sorry if my question is basic.

I have a class , let's say Time as below:

```
Class Time {
public:
    Time(int, int, int);
    void setTime(int,int,int);
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};
```

I have

```
Time t1(0,0,0);
Time t2(0,0,0);
```

Now if I change

```
t1.hour=12;
```

Then I want t2.hour also change.
Thanks.

P.S. I actually uses these two in different classes that I want them to sync.

Comment: Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: It's probably easier to understand your question if you show some code on how you would like it to behave.

Comment: I change the question by adding an example similar but more clear to what I meant.

Comment: You have two different classes that both have a `Time` member? Or you have different classes that have similar members you want to relate?

Comment: I have two different objects t1 and t2 both have member hour.

Comment: Do you only want the hour member synced but t1 and t2 can have different minutes and seconds?

Comment: Yes, That's right. I found out about static class member. Can it be the solution?

Comment: The two objects are independent of one another. Changing one cannot change the other unless they refer to the same object. You could use some kind of controller to sync them perhaps.

Comment: Yes. Making the hour member static means there is only one "hour" member and it is shared amongst all objects of the class.

Comment: Your question is profoundly unclear.   Can you change the `Time` class?   Is there any code that has access to both objects at the same time?    As you've described it, you have two unrelated objects with no way of relating the two, but you want them to be synced.   It will be impossible to sync them unless there is some discernible relationship between them (e.g.  some code that changes one has visibility of the other, so can change it too).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment and suggestions. As discussed with doug, making hour static solved the problem as below:

```
Class Time {
public:
Time(int, int, int);
void setTime(int,int,int);
static int hour;
int minute;
int second;
};
```

And then I needed to access hour as below:

```
Time::hour=12;
```